# how to give dynamic input for RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph?

Tags: ruby, ruby-rgl

I am new to RGL. I want to show a graph of all parent and children type relations.
I have written the following code.

My code is as:

**`require 'rgl/adjacency'` 

`require 'rgl/dot'` 

`input_arr = [1,2,2,3,2,4,4,5,6,4,1,6]`**




We need to give input as following to generate graph.

**`dg=RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[1,2,2,3,2,4,4,5,6,4,1,6]`

`dg.write_to_graphic_file('jpg')`**

But I want to give the array dynamically, ie I want to pass **input_arr**. But it is not working.
can anybody explain how to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I could solve my issue.

I have written like the folowing:

I have processed my main_arr variable something like this.
**`main_arr=[[1,2],[2,3],[2,4],[4,5],[6,4],[1,6]]`


`dg=RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[]`


    `main_arr.each do |ma|`

        `dg.add_edge ma[0],ma[1]`

    `end`**

Now it is working fine.
Now I can pass any dynamic values to generate graph.